# Why can issuing the same command create more output in tty than in pts/gnome-terminal?

Tags: tty, gnome-terminal, stdout, stderr

gnome-terminal:

```
$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for user: 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: .background_cache.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
done
```

tty1 as accessed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>:

```
$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for user: 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: .background_cache.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
[ 1603.545926] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
... (repeats twice)
[ 1603.560671] FAT-fs (sda2): invalid media value (0x4c)
... (repeats once)
[ 1603.573245] qnx4: no qnx4 filesystem (no root dir).
done
```

While attempting to redirect the output of the tty1 to be able to directly copy it here I noticed that these additional lines are not coming from either stdout or stderr of the command. Where from then? Why?

Comment: You may notice that those lines still appear on tty1 when you run the command in the gnome terminal.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They're coming from the kernel. You'll see them also by running

```
dmesg
```

Kernel messages are displayed on virtual console by default; they aren't in X terminal emulators (such as GNOME Terminal).